# Lifetime inferencing across match arms for enum

Tags: rust, lifetime

Here I have an Enum, with a lifetime for only one of its variant.

- In the match arms, the variant with the lifetime reference returns.
- If so, why does it complain about the second borrow for the path that uses the second match arm (for the variant that has no lifetime reference)

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb38f3a8f1f0b47d50d5fb30d87cb8af)

```rust
  1 pub enum Pqr<'a> {
  2     Address(&'a mut u64),
  3     Size(usize),
  4 }
  5
  6 pub struct Xyz<'a> {
  7     pqr: Pqr<'a>,
  8     new_val: u64,
  9
 10 }
 11
 12
 13 fn ret_addr<'a>(xyz: &'a mut Xyz) -> &'a mut u64 {
 14     match &mut xyz.pqr {
 15         Pqr::Address(a) => { return *a;},
 16         Pqr::Size(_) => {},
 17     }
 18     xyz.pqr = Pqr::Size(20);
 19     &mut xyz.new_val
 20 }
 21
 22 fn main() {
 23     let mut val = 10;
 24     let pqr = Pqr::Address(&mut val);
 25     let mut xyz = Xyz { pqr, new_val: 20};
 26     let val =    ret_addr(&mut xyz);
 27     println!("val is {}", val);
 28 }
```

This results in the following error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `xyz.pqr` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
13 | fn ret_addr<'a>(xyz: &'a mut Xyz) -> &'a mut u64 {
   |             -- lifetime `'a` defined here
14 |     match &mut xyz.pqr {
   |           ------------ borrow of `xyz.pqr` occurs here
15 |         Pqr::Address(a) => { return *a;},
   |                                     -- returning this value requires that `xyz.pqr` is borrowed for `'a`
...
18 |     xyz.pqr = Pqr::Size(20);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `xyz.pqr` occurs here
```

My question is the path that borrows xyz.pqr at line 14 immediately returns. So if the execution reaches line 18, there is no pending borrow at all. What might I be missing?

Comment: That's a problem with the current borrowck, and will be solved with Polonius (and this question is a duplicate, I just need to find it...)

Comment: Thanks @ChayimFriedman this helps. Would this problem also appear if I use a 'if' statement instead? I will fiddle around the control flow logic to get past this.
Are there known patterns for working around this?

Comment: It is indepedent of the control flow construct used. I don't know a workaround, but there might be.

Comment: This RFC, I think, is also very helpful in understanding the details: [RFC Problem #3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions)